# Genetic algorithm - shortest path in weighted graph

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I want to make a genetic algorithm that solves a shortest path problem in weighted, connected graph. Similar to travelling salesman, but instead of fully-connected graph, it's just connected.

My idea is to randomly generate a path consisting of n-1 nodes for each chromosome in binary form, where numbers indicate nodes in a path. Then I will choose the best depending on sum of weights (if cant go from A to B i would give it penalty) and crossover/mutate bits in it. Will it work? It feels a little like smaller version of bruteforce. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genetic algorithm is pretty much "smaller version of bruteforce". It is just a meta**heuristic**, not an optimization method which has decent convergence guarantees. It basically depends on randomness to provide new solutions, thus it is a "slightly better random search".

So "will it work"? Yes, it will do something, as long as you have enough randomness in mutation it will even (eventually) converge to optimum. Will it work better than a random search? Hard to say, this depends on dozens of factors, not only your encoding, but also all the hyperparameters used etc. in general genetic algorithms are about trials and errors. In particular representation of chromosomes which does not loose any information (yours does not) **does not matter**, meaning that everything depends on clever implementation of crossover and mutation (as long as chromosomes do not loose any information they are all equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

You can use permutation coding GA. In permutation coding, you should give the start and end points. GA searches for the best chromosome with your fitness function. Candidate solutions (chromosomes) will be like 2-5-4-3-1 or 2-3-1-4-5 or 1-2-5-4-3 etc. So your solution depends on your fitness function. (Look at GA package for R to apply permutation GA easily.)

Connections are constraints for your problem. My best advice is create a constraint matrix like that:

```
FirstPoint SecondPoint Connected
A          B           true
A          C           true
A          E           false
...        ...         ...
```

In standard TSP, just distances are considered. In your fitness function, you have to consider this matrix and add a penalty to return value for each false.

```
Example chromosome: A-B-E-D-C
A-B: 1
B-E: 1
E-D: 4
D-C: 3

Fitness value: 9
```

.

```
Example chromosome: A-E-B-C-D
A-E: penalty
E-B: 1
B-C: 6
C-D: 3

Fitness value: 10 + penalty value.
```

Because your constraint is a hard constraint, you can use max integer value as the penalty. GA will find the best solution. :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/FmSQY
Something like that. ABEDC would be the shortest path I need to find.